# Ruby STDIN.gets return nil directly while running in Sublime Text2

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I wrote a simple ruby code:

```
puts gets
puts STDIN.gets
```

It runs ok in the console, but when I run  it with <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> in Sublime Text2 it printed nothing and doesn't prompt for input; It seems that `gets` return `nil` directly.

I checked the file Ruby.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Users/yangbin/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

And ran the command `/Users/yangbin/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby test.rb`, I was prompted to input something and it printed ok.

```
yangbin$ /Users/yangbin/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby test.rb
hello
hello
```

What's wrong with the configuration with ruby in Sublime Text2 ?

Comment: Sublime Text does not support input through the build system. You might want to take a look at https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL

Comment: It's important to understand that Sublime is NOT an IDE. It's a very powerful text editor with some features in common with an IDE. The two are not the same, nor should they be. I'd recommend becoming familiar with using IRB, and a debugger, in parallel with Sublime or Vim or Emacs. That's a common editing/testing/debugging toolset that works on all systems, even where Sublime won't run.

Comment: It's not a IDE, I got it. Thanks a lot.