# Ruby -- 'gets' adds newline character

Tags: ruby, gets

I wrote this:

```
print "Enter your name:"
name = gets
puts "Hello #{name}. Please to meet you."
```

and the result was like this:

```
Hello Moemen
. Pleased to meet you
```

- Why is the remainder of the string after the variable continued in another line? I want it to be `"Hello Moemen. Pleased to meet you."` Am I missing something?
- I'm using sublime text 2, and I couldn't get the `gets` method to let me input data; it just prints the outcome in the console without giving me a chance to input anything. Any idea?

Comment: for your second question, it's probably because `gets` pulls from `stdin`, which sublime text 2 might not pipe into the program.  maybe look up how to get interactive mode/stdin to work in sublime

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432524/why-does-rubys-gets-includes-the-closing-newline

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437814/ruby-stdin-gets-return-nil-directly-while-running-in-sublime-text2

Answer (score 6):

When you use `gets`, the input is going to be followed by a newline so you will need to strip the newline before printing it out.

```
print "Enter your name:"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello #{name}. Pleased to meet you."
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks everyone. please close the question. I got everything I need

Answer (score 1):

What you report would not happen. It cannot be true. When you get a string by `gets`, you may get a string like `"Moemen\n"`. Since an input is delimited by `"\n"`, the string has that at the end. When it is interpolated into `"Hello #{name}. Please to meet you."`, you would get:

```
Hello Moemen
. Please to meet you.
```

but not

```
Hello Moemen
. Pleased to meet you
```

as you report. That does not happen.

In order to get `"Hello Moemen. Pleased to meet you."`, you need to change the string to `"Hello #{name.chomp}. Pleased to meet you."`.